# macOS Catalina: MacBook Air Corrupted HD Partition Map

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, catalina

My MacBook Air is not working after installing macOS Catalina. I tried everything to erase the hard drive using Disk Utility and `diskutil` command, but it won't just let me.

I tried booting into Internet Recovery mode, and reinstall macOS, but no success. I also noticed lots of weird partitions in the `diskutil list` option.

How do I resolve this issue?

I believe it has to do with `gpt` command, but I'm not familiar with using it. I also tried using GParted, but it kept giving me input/output error.

[image: Disk Util List]
[image: GPT -R Show]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: All the *"weird partitions"* (disk3 -> disk21) are ram disk because you are booted into recovery.  Don't worry about them - it is normal.  `disk1` you don't want to look at as it is a synthesized disk not a real one.  Your `fdisk /dev/disk0` and `gpt -r show disk0` shows corrupt/missing partition table though.   What error do you get *exactly* when you try to [erase it](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208496) from recovery?

Comment: i can't erase the hd at all tried to verify/repair no success as well ... the Disk Utility shows two partition one macOs and the other called macOs - Data ( Weird ) both won't be erased or formatted ! tried to do it through disk utility and diskutil command through terminal !

one of the errors i get is there's no map ?
so do i have to fix the HD through gpt command first or what to do ? 
Thanks a lot for replying :)

Comment: i managed to wipe the ssd using linux rescue live ... by using  dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdx bs=8M && sync this command